# Changing two verbs from active to passive in one sentence

Tags: passive-voice

Could you please change this sentence into passive voice?

> The pitcher plant traps and digests small animals.

Being confused because of two verbs in active voice

Comment: Small animals are trapped and digested by the pitcher plant.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> Small animals are trapped and digested by the pitcher plant.